# Bad address error with errno in execle() function

Tags: c

My goal is learning how to execle() function work. And I found this code in the Head First C book.

This is main process Code(diner_info.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        printf("Diners: %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("Juice: %s\n", getenv("JUICE"));
        return 0;
}
```

And this is contains the execle() function(my_exec_program.c):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

        char *my_env[] = {"JUICE=peach and apple", NULL};

int main()
{

        execle("diner_info", "diner_info", 4, NULL, my_env);
        puts(strerror(errno));

        return 0;
}
```

When I compiled the all c files, I didn't get an error. But When I ran the compiled file(my_exec_program), I get this result from the my_exec_program:

```
Bad address
```

Someone help me how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `4` gets treated as a pointer to `char`. If you want to pass 4 as an `argv` argument, it needs to be a string: `"4"`.

Comment: Thanks buddy.It works. The solution was quite easy. And this is a stupid question for Stackoverflow so I'll delete this question.

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question. All that deleting an answered question does is give us less incentive to help you in the future. (Since you're also deleting all our answers.)

Comment: @H.Emre: You can't delete the question — there are multiple up-voted answers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK. Actually I take 5 reputation for this question. I made a good start in 2017, I learned two important things. First, use correct data type and the second DON'T DELETE your question with answers. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
    execle("diner_info", "diner_info", 4, NULL, my_env);
```

to:

```
execle("diner_info", "diner_info", "4", (char*)0, my_env);
```

You want to pass a string as argument whereas the int value 4 is considered as address. The variable number of arguments taken by [`execle()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) is all C-strings, terminated by a null pointer.

Note: when using `NULL` be aware that, if `NULL` is defined as `#define NULL 0` then `exec*()` variadic functions won't work as expected.
Instead I'd use `(char*)0` instead of `NULL` just to be safe.